# How to upgrade Android Application

Tags: android

I have developed android application.Current version is : `android:versionCode="1"` and `android:versionName="2.0.3"`

Sales Rep is going to use this application.

1 ) When They are in the field/working plac, if there are application upgrade available how we are going indicate to them?

2) Its a private application.They don't like to put in the android market place. So I thought  we create one web application in PHP/other language & using that application user enter their credential/login to go home screen &  in that place I want to take the my android application's version number. (that means need to show current version & new version). Is it possible to do this?

3) My application size is 7MB.So when they upgrade the application its overwriting previous version ? or uninstall application & install it?

4) When we do the application upgrade, apk file will download to the internal storage & upgrade it.after upgradehas been successfully the downloaded apk will remove it?

Thanks in advance...

I am expecting your suggestion.Please help me out from this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distribution is easy: Just put you apk on some predefined loaction in web server (do not forget to configure proper mime type)  - then field people will be able to install it  by just clicking on link in their android webbrowser / email program.

To inform them about new version you can:

- send email to them
- deposit version number somewhere on webserver, and check  it in your app. When new version is available you can prompt them for upgrade

Comment: it depends on your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

There are several other Android Markets that are just apps you install and run.

You can configure them to point to your own repository of apps.

Then you just increase your apps versions number as normal, release a new version into your repository and the market app will alert the user.

Some of them don't provide security against someone finding your server and downloading the code directly, but at least they wont be in the Google Android Market for all to find.

http://f-droid.org/ can be configured to do this. There are others I can't remember at the moment.